# How to Thread-safe a ClientDataSet on a worker thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a really slow query that always make windows mark my program as Not responding. I decided to create a background worker to perform this query while the main thread show a GIF. I did everything and it works! =D

But... When I close my Form I got a EInvalidPointer Exception, ONLY when I use the worker thread.

Here is my code:

Main thread Call to worker thread

```
if not TThreadDB.ExecutarThreadDB(cdsSolicitacao,
                                   FConsultaSql,
                                   nil,
                                   tpHigher) then
 begin
   Exit;
 end;
```

Where:
 cdsSolicitacao is a clientDataSet I want to share between the threads,
 FConsultaSql string (my query)

My thread Unit

```
unit UThreadDB;

interface 

uses Classes, DBClient, DB, SysUtils, Variants, JvJCLUtils;

type

  TParametros = class
  private
    FTotal: Integer;
    FCampo: array of string;
    FTipo: array of TFieldType;
    FValor: array of Variant;
  public
    constructor Create(ACampos: string; ATipos: array of TFieldType; AValores: array of Variant); reintroduce;
  end;

  TThreadDB = class(TThread)
  private
    FExecutou: Boolean;
    FClientDataSet: TClientDataSet;
    FConsultaSQL: string;
    FParametros: TParametros;
    procedure CarregarDados;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean; AClientDataSet: TClientDataSet; AConsultaSQL: string = '';
      AParametros: TParametros = nil); reintroduce;

    class function ExecutarThreadDB(AClientDataSet: TClientDataSet; AConsultaSQL: string = '';
      AParametros: TParametros = nil; APriority: TThreadPriority = tpNormal): Boolean;

    class procedure ExecutarThreadDBParalela(AThreadDB: TThreadDB; AClientDataSet: TClientDataSet;
      AConsultaSQL: string = ''; AParametros: TParametros = nil; APriority: TThreadPriority = tpNormal);
  end;

implementation

uses
   BIBLIO;

{ TThreadDB }

class function TThreadDB.ExecutarThreadDB(AClientDataSet: TClientDataSet; AConsultaSQL: string = '';
   AParametros: TParametros = nil; APriority: TThreadPriority = tpNormal): Boolean;
var
   lThreadDB: TThreadDB;
begin
   lThreadDB := TThreadDB.Create(True, AClientDataSet, AConsultaSQL, AParametros);

   try

      //lThreadDB.FreeOnTerminate := True;
      lThreadDB.Priority := APriority;
      lThreadDB.Resume;

      lThreadDB.WaitFor;

      Result := lThreadDB.FExecutou;

   finally
      lThreadDB.Terminate;

      //lThreadDB := nil;
      FreeAndNil(lThreadDB);
   end;
end;

class procedure TThreadDB.ExecutarThreadDBParalela(AThreadDB: TThreadDB; AClientDataSet: TClientDataSet;
   AConsultaSQL: string = ''; AParametros: TParametros = nil; APriority: TThreadPriority = tpNormal);
begin
   AThreadDB := TThreadDB.Create(True, AClientDataSet, AConsultaSQL, AParametros);

   AThreadDB.FreeOnTerminate := True;
   AThreadDB.Priority := APriority;
   AThreadDB.Resume;
end;

procedure TThreadDB.CarregarDados;
var
   lIndex: Integer;
begin
   FClientDataSet.Close;

   try

      if (FConsultaSQL <> '') then
      begin
         FClientDataSet.CommandText := FConsultaSQL;
      end;

      if (FParametros <> nil) then
      begin
         for lIndex := 0 to (FParametros.FTotal - 1) do
         begin
            case FParametros.FTipo[lIndex] of
               ftInteger : FClientDataSet.Params.ParamByName(FParametros.FCampo[lindex]).AsInteger := FParametros.FValor[lIndex];
               ftString  : FClientDataSet.Params.ParamByName(FParametros.FCampo[lindex]).AsString  := FParametros.FValor[lIndex];
               ftDate    : FClientDataSet.Params.ParamByName(FParametros.FCampo[lindex]).AsDate    := FParametros.FValor[lIndex];
            end;
         end;
      end;

      FClientDataSet.Open;

      FExecutou := True;

   except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Erro('Não foi possível carregar os dados solicitados!' + #13 +
             'Classe do erro: ' + E.ClassName + #13 +
             'Mensagem: ' + E.Message);
      end;
   end;

   if (FParametros <> nil) then
   begin
      FreeAndNil(FParametros);
   end;
end;

constructor TThreadDB.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean; AClientDataSet: TClientDataSet; AConsultaSQL: string = '';
   AParametros: TParametros = nil);
begin
  inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);

   FClientDataSet := AClientDataSet;

   FConsultaSQL := AConsultaSQL;

   FParametros := AParametros;

   FExecutou := False;
end;

procedure TThreadDB.Execute;
begin
   CarregarDados;
end;

{ TParametros }

constructor TParametros.Create(ACampos: string; ATipos: array of TFieldType; AValores: array of Variant);
var
   lIndex: Integer;
begin
  inherited Create;

   FTotal := ContaCaracteres(ACampos, ';') + 1;

   SetLength(FCampo, FTotal);
   SetLength(FTipo, FTotal);
   SetLength(FValor, FTotal);

   for lIndex := 0 to FTotal - 1 do
   begin
      FCampo[lIndex] := ExtractDelimited(lIndex + 1, ACampos , [';']);
   end;

   for lIndex := 0 to FTotal - 1 do
   begin
      FTipo[lIndex] := ATipos[lIndex];
   end;

   for lIndex := 0 to FTotal - 1 do
   begin
      FValor[lIndex] := AValores[lIndex];
   end;
end;

end.
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Comment: The majority of your code (this is all out of context). And some time in the debugger to figure out where exactly it's happening.

Comment: I edited with some info that might make my issue clearer

Comment: This is not your actual code, because you don't call `TThread.Execute` yourself; it's called automatically when the thread is started. If you want help with your code, **post your code**, not something you invented for your post. Don't waste people's time trying to solve a problem without posting your actual code. See [mcve].

Comment: Like Ken said the code you posted doesn't really match what you describe. How does this let your Main thread animate a gif? The call from the Main thread is waiting for your DbThread, nothing paralell. This should be blocking the main thread, doesn't it? How can I close the form and get the described EInvalidPointerException then?

Comment: As to sharing a ClientDataset between threads, this could potentially cause your exception. ExecutarThreadDBParalela is letting the thread do work with a reference to  ClientDataset that might be destroyed without your thread ever noticing. And your design won't let the main thread shutdown running DBThreads.

Comment: @Nil. I didn't put the animated gif part because I didn't think it was important for the question, I just want to know how to share a clientDataSet between two threads. Yeah. It is blocking my main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned that in your question, but I guess the problem you describe may be caused by modifying dataset object, which is at the same time consumed by the main thread (displayed in a grid, for example). In other words, that you're passing to a worker thread dataset, which is linked to some controls in your main thread. Or, yet another way described, your **cdsSolicitacao** dataset object is linked through data source object to some control(s) on your main form.

Do note that **main thread cannot ever work with an object that is being modified by a worker thread**.

And even modal animation won't stop main thread from consuming that just modified dataset. For example DB grid can be requested for repaint which needs access to its underlying dataset which is at the same time being modified by a worker thread.

If that is your case, and you don't want to create a new dataset instance that you then replace with the consumed one when the worker thread finishes,
you'll need to (ideally) disconnect that dataset object from every linked control before passing to the worker thread and reconnect when finishes.

Comment: That exactly my case, man!  So in order release my UI thread I have to either create a new dataset inside my worker thread and replace the one I'm currenctly sharing or disconnect the dataset. Thanks a lot. I'll try it!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that's the correct way to fix the issue(s) (either you create a new instance by the main thread passing it to the worker thread, or produce one by the worker thread, or disconnect existing one from all the linked controls). P.S. I'm not a man :D

Comment: I'm sorry, @Victoria! I'm so desperate looking for a way to solve this issue that i didn't even read your name. Thanks again! =D